# How to run next step based on the result of the previous Step in SQL server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a conditional Sql server Agent job.My requirement is in the first step is to count the number of rows in a particular table,If the count of rows is 0 then don't go to next step and if count of rows is 1 or more then Go to next step.

How can i write a stored procedure in step 1 so that it gets failed when the count is '0' ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can raise an error in the stored procedure using RAISERROR()